# What is the best way to load data from Redshift back into Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a use case where our ETL, built on Redshift, is effectively the "brains" of the operation. The production database, which will be built on top of Postgres, is meant to solely ingest data from what has been normalized/calculated in Redshift.

What is the best way to go about doing this? I have thought of:

- SNS > SQS > API
- Airflow (COPY) > API

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I never went in that direction.  The answer depends entirely on your use case.  What is the schedule like?  Will Redshift be producing transactions that need to be loaded immediately into PostgreSQL?  Or will it be producing datasets for updates to or replacement of reference tables a few times a day?

Comment: Have you tried using `pg_dump`? See: [Is there a way to do a SQL dump from Amazon Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15440794/174777)